# Cannot stream video in Gingerbread device

Tags: android, stream, android-videoview, mp4

I have an mp4 file I have converted using handbrake using H.264 Baseline encoding. This streams fine in browser.

I have created an app that would stream this video in a VideoView. I have tested in 4.0.1 and 4.3 and it works fine. The video plays perfectly fine.

Using a 2.3.3 android emulator, I can hear the sound but there's not video. When I tried it in an actual 2.3.3 device (HTC Evo), it cannot play the video at all. I get a "This video cannot be played" error. I'm not so sure whether this is supported in gingerbread but it would seem like so since the emulator can at least play the audio.

I saw some HDMI permission info in the logcat but I'm not exactly sure what it means. I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Here's the logcat:

```
01-29 18:42:19.775: D/@@@@(1297): GameDetailFragment onPause
01-29 18:42:20.116: V/MediaPlayer(1297): constructor E
01-29 18:42:20.116: I/AudioSystem(1297): getting audio flinger
01-29 18:42:20.116: I/AudioSystem(1297): returning new audio session id
01-29 18:42:20.116: V/MediaPlayer(1297): constructor X
01-29 18:42:20.116: V/MediaPlayer(1297): setListener
01-29 18:42:20.116: D/MediaPlayer(1297): hasHDMIPermission: -1
01-29 18:42:20.116: D/MediaPlayer(1297): registerHDMINotification
01-29 18:42:20.116: E/HDMIStatusObserver(1297): status: UNPLUG
01-29 18:42:20.116: D/MediaPlayer(1297): isHDMIPlug(): false
01-29 18:42:20.126: E/MediaPlayer(1297): onHDMIStateChanged
01-29 18:42:20.126: E/MediaPlayer(1297): hdmi_setting not found!
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/hdmi_setting (No such file or directory)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:132)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.readHDMISetting(MediaPlayer.java:2245)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.getHDMIResolution(MediaPlayer.java:2124)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:564)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:217)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:49)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:482)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:551)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1961)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1600)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1321)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1957)
01-29 18:42:20.126: W/System.err(1297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 18:42:20.136: W/System.err(1297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-29 18:42:20.136: W/System.err(1297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
01-29 18:42:20.136: W/System.err(1297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 18:42:20.136: W/System.err(1297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-29 18:42:20.136: W/System.err(1297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-29 18:42:20.136: W/System.err(1297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-29 18:42:20.136: W/System.err(1297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 18:42:20.136: D/MediaPlayer(1297): getHDMIResolution: 00
01-29 18:42:20.136: D/MediaPlayer(1297): setDataSource(Context context, /, Map<String, String> headers) in
01-29 18:42:20.136: V/MediaPlayer(1297): setDataSource(/)
01-29 18:42:20.136: D/MediaPlayer(1297): setDataSource(Context context, /, Map<String, String> headers) out, scheme == null || scheme.equals(file)
01-29 18:42:20.136: V/MediaPlayer(1297): setVideoSurface
01-29 18:42:20.136: V/MediaPlayer(1297): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
01-29 18:42:20.136: V/MediaPlayer(1297): setVideoSurface
01-29 18:42:20.136: V/MediaPlayer(1297): prepareAsync
01-29 18:42:20.146: V/MediaPlayer(1297): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
01-29 18:42:20.146: E/MediaPlayer(1297): error (1, -2147483648)
01-29 18:42:20.146: V/MediaPlayer(1297): callback application
01-29 18:42:20.146: V/MediaPlayer(1297): back from callback
01-29 18:42:20.156: E/MediaPlayer(1297): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-29 18:42:20.156: D/VideoView(1297): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-29 18:42:21.307: D/MediaPlayer(1297): reset() in
01-29 18:42:21.307: V/MediaPlayer(1297): reset
01-29 18:42:21.307: D/MediaPlayer(1297): reset() out
01-29 18:42:21.307: D/MediaPlayer(1297): release() in
01-29 18:42:21.307: D/MediaPlayer(1297): unregisterHDMINotification
01-29 18:42:21.307: E/HDMIStatusObserver(1297): status: UNPLUG
01-29 18:42:21.307: E/HDMIStatusObserver(1297): onEvent: false
01-29 18:42:21.307: V/MediaPlayer(1297): setListener
01-29 18:42:21.307: V/MediaPlayer(1297): disconnect
01-29 18:42:21.307: V/MediaPlayer(1297): destructor
01-29 18:42:21.307: V/MediaPlayer(1297): disconnect
01-29 18:42:21.307: D/MediaPlayer(1297): release() out
```

Comment: Adding the code you are using to play the video might be useful.

Comment: It turns out to be an internet connection problem. The phone is connected to wifi but not getting any internet. The logcat mislead me to think it was some incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the [supported media formats page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) on developer.android.com shows that H.264 (.mp4) playback is supported on all versions of Android (assuming I am reading the chart correctly), so playback in the VideoView should work. However, streaming from an HTTPS URL is not supported before Android 3.0, which would cause an error if you are indeed attempting to stream from an HTTPS URL.